# How to manage the transparent spacing while creating icons in ai?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, icon

I tried creating icons using ai but got stuck while managing consistency.
I want to achieve the result shown in the Image. For every icon, I'll create.

Updated Image
[image: Image2]

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? Are you facing issue after you have exported icons or even in illustrator while working on them?

Comment: How are you creating the outside green house line? I would be using path offset to get an equal space around the inside of the house.

Comment: Offset or a second stroke on the outer line thats 100% transparent set to knock out the group the icon is in. Benefit of later is that the thing is live should you modify things. Alternatively offset full inner shape inwards as effect it toovis editable.

Comment: @AndrewH So basically I am trying to trace that image using pen tool. Its quite simple to trace though. But then when I want other icons for example profile, wallet, notification. Then in that case how to manage that spacing around?

Comment: @Vikas I have updated the image. In case you did not understand the previous one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a stroke and Offset Path in the Appearance panel.

First create a basic shape, give it a stroke and fill. Then hit the ***Fx*** button in the Appearance Panel, choose *Path > Offset path*.  You could do the same for all your icons - setting the same offset for all of them. The offset can be set numerically so they are all the same. Double click the Offset Path in the panel to bring up the dialog where you can change the amount.

[image]

Then once you have done that, you can do *Object > Expand Appearance*, and make additional edits or add additional strokes, etc. Note that expanding the appearance bakes in the effect so that it is no longer editable as an effect.

[image]

It's possible to use this technique for all kinds of shapes, even for  compound paths, for example in the bell icon here.

[image]

Comment: Adding to this, you can also save the appearance of your selected shape to the Graphic Styles panel and apply it to other shapes easily, or export the graphic styles for use in other files.

Comment: @Billy Kerr Thank you. It worked in my case. I really appreciate the amount of knowledge you guys have. Thanks again :)